# Magento 2 Error: Property "xxx" does not have corresponding setter in class

Tags: magento, magento2

We are utilizing Magento 2.1 and installed this [Store Pickup module](https://marketplace.magento.com/magedelight-storepickup.html) that did not install correctly.

The module is disabled through SSH and now we get errors on Checkout related to Store Pickup.

From the logs:

```
Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-5b689909809ce; Message: Property "PickupStore" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationExtensionInterface". in /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195
Stack trace:
#0 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(LogicException))
#1 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(219): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(LogicException))
#2 /home/reorder/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#5 /home/reorder/public_html/routes.php(225): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#6 /home/reorder/public_html/wingstop/index.php(6): include('/home/reorder/p...')
#7 {main} [] []
[2018-08-06 18:54:13] main.CRITICAL: LogicException: Property "PickupStore" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationExtensionInterface". in /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/NameFinder.php:100
Stack trace:
#0 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/NameFinder.php(59): Magento\Framework\Reflection\NameFinder->findAccessorMethodName(Object(Zend\Code\Reflection\ClassReflection), 'PickupStore', 'getPickupStore', 'isPickupStore')
#1 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(158): Magento\Framework\Reflection\NameFinder->getGetterMethodName(Object(Zend\Code\Reflection\ClassReflection), 'PickupStore')
#2 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(322): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->_createFromArray('\\Magento\\Checko...', Array)
#3 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(175): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->convertValue(Array, '\\Magento\\Checko...')
#4 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(322): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->_createFromArray('Magento\\Checkou...', Array)
#5 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(119): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->convertValue(Array, 'Magento\\Checkou...')
#6 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(101): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->process('Magento\\Checkou...', 'saveAddressInfo...', Array)
#7 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(299): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver->resolve()
#8 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()
#9 /home/reorder/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /home/reorder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#12 /home/reorder/public_html/routes.php(225): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#13 /home/reorder/public_html/wingstop/index.php(6): include('/home/reorder/p...')
#14 {main}
```

From what I gather I should try and find the `extension_attributes.xml` and possibly remove it from there?

If so I cannot find it; is this what I should even be looking for?  Any help would be greatly appreciated as users cannot continue past the Shipping Options screen on checkout now.

Also [from this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169304/magento2-error-does-not-have-corresponding-setter-in-class-magento-checkout-api) I am a bit worried to delete ALL the folders in my generation folder.  Whenever this Magento 2 instance generates new folders and files / deploys content it always seems to mess something up.

Answer (score 0):

1) Place the store into maintenance mode

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

2) delete generation and DI contents

```
rm -rf var/generation/*
rm -rf var/di/*
```

3) re-generate these, using the compiler

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

4) disable maintenance mode

```
bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

What do you mean by always messes things up? That's probably due to permissions issues on your setup..